# What's wrong with preg_match_all and my string?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have a series of tag in the text that I want to match with `preg_match_all` but the `$regex` string has something wrong and I can't understand what to do.

```
$tagReplace = ['mov', 'flv', 'youtube'];
foreach ($tagReplace as $plg_tag) {
    $regex = "#{" . $plg_tag . "}(.*?){/" . $plg_tag . "}#s";
    $var = preg_match_all($regex, "{mov}the_video_url{/mov}", $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
    var_dump($matches);
}
```

Comment: *I want to replace with preg_match_all* it does not change the string

Comment: You have a syntax error on the very first line `$tagReplace = [mov, flv, youtube];`

Comment: Are mov, flv, youtube constants?

Comment: `foreach ($tagReplace as $plg_tag)` - because now you find 0,1,2 instead of mov, flv...

Comment: @splash58 I've correct the question

Comment: @Andreas yes, you where right. Corrected but that wasn't the main problem.

Comment: Change `{` into `\\{` and do the same for `}` and `/` since those have special meaning in regex

Comment: @Andreas I made a search on how to prepare the regex string and I didn't find nothing I can understand. I'm really not good in regex... sorry.

Comment: `#` and `#s` serve no purpose in your regex since they do not exist in `{mov}the_video_url{/mov}`

Comment: Also, use `preg_quote( $plg_tag )` instead of just `$plg_tag`

Comment: It seems to work prety fine for me! What is your expected result?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

 $matches = array();
 $p = '/(mov|flv|youtube)/';
 $replace_to = 'your text you want to be insted of the mov or flv or youtube';
 $str = ' the string that you want to work on and replace its content';

$p_c = array(
             $p => function($match) {
                   $ret = str_replace("mov", $replace_to, $match[0]);
                   $ret = str_replace("flv", $replace_to, $ret);
                   $ret = str_replace("youtube", $replace_to, $ret);

                   return $ret;
             }
 );

 $res3 = preg_replace_callback_array($p_c, $str);
```